# What does “bolted a little out “ and “ stand a trifle “ mean here?

Tags: meaning

“you have **bolted a little out** of course, as young fellows often do; and you shall never have another chance, nor the ghost of half a one.' The wild young grandson makes answer to this and says, 'You're as rich as rich can be; you have been at no uncommon expense on my account, you're saving up piles of money for my little sister that lives with you in a secret, stealthy, hugger-muggering kind of way and with no manner of enjoyment—why can't you **stand a trifle** for your grown-up relation?' The jolly old grandfather unto this, retorts, not only that he declines to fork out with that cheerful readiness which is always so agreeable and pleasant in a gentleman of his time of life, but that he will bow up, and call names, and make reflections whenever they meet. Then the plain question is, an't it a pity that this state of things should continue, and how much better would it be for the gentleman to hand over a reasonable amount of tin, and make it all right and comfortable?”

Excerpt From
The Old Curiosity Shop
Charles Dickens

Comment: I can't help but notice that this is the fifth question you've asked about a passage from *The Old Curiosity Shop.* I would suggest that you do more research before asking ELU.

Comment: @alphabet agreed. The questioner should look at dictionary meanings of bolt and trifle before asking this question.

Comment: _Stand_ in the sense _Provide (food or drink) for (someone) at one's own expense.
"somebody in the bar would stand him a beer"._

Comment: @KateBunting   
I am grateful for your help.

Comment: The meaning of bolt is very standard and in any good dictionary.